# Warnings in sorting an array of a structure with bubble sort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, compiler-warnings, bubble-sort

I created 2 structures one called product and one called order.

What i wanted was to sort an array consisting of orders and those orders included an array of products and i used a bubble sort algorithm to do it.

The program works well, but the problem is that its giving some weird warnings that i cant seem to understand.

Structures:

product:

```
/* Structures */
typedef struct product 
{
   int ident;
   char desc[MAX_CHARS]; /* string that describes a product eg. "bread" */
   int price;  /* price of the product*/
   int weight; /* weight of the product eg. 2kg */
   int quant; /* quantity of the product in stock */
   int state_prod;
}product;
```

order:

```
typedef struct order 
{
   int ident_o;
   product set_prod[MAX_PRODS_OD]; /* Set of products */
   int state;
}order;
```

bubble sort algorithm:

```
void swap(char * xp,char * yp) 
{ 
    char * temp = xp; 
    xp = yp; 
    yp = temp; 
} 

/* A function to implement bubble sort */
void bubbleSort(product arr[], int n) 
{ 
   int i, j; 
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)       

       /* Last i elements are already in place */ 
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)  
           if (arr[j].desc > arr[j+1].desc) 
              swap(&arr[j].desc, &arr[j+1].desc); 
}
```

I can only compile using this command "gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ansi -pedantic".

Warnings:

```
In function ‘bubbleSort’:
error: passing argument 1 of ‘swap’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
               swap(&arr[j].desc, &arr[j+1].desc);
                    ^
note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[64]’
 void swap(char * xp,char * yp)
      ^~~~

error: passing argument 2 of ‘swap’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
               swap(&arr[j].desc, &arr[j+1].desc);
                                  ^
note: expected ‘char *’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[64]’
 void swap(char * xp,char * yp)
      ^~~~
```

Comment: Arrays automatically decay to pointers when used as function arguments, you don't need to use `&`. That changes the type from `char *` to `char **`.

Comment: You're only swapping the descriptions, you need to swap the entire structure.

Comment: You cannot swap arrays by swapping the pointers the arrays decay into. This should also be a hint that your `swap()` function is completely useless.

Answer (score 0):

This error message

```
error: passing argument 1 of ‘swap’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
               swap(&arr[j].desc, &arr[j+1].desc);
```

means that you passed to the function a pointer to an array declared like

```
char desc[MAX_CHARS];
```

using for example the expression `&arr[j].desc` that has the type `char( * )[MAX_CHARS]`. But the function parameter has the type `char *`. You have at least to write

```
swap( arr[j].desc, arr[j+1].desc);
```

However the function swap itself is incorrect.  It does not swap elements of the character arrays.

```
void swap(char * xp,char * yp) 
{ 
    char * temp = xp; 
    xp = yp; 
    yp = temp; 
}
```

You could define it for example the following way

```
void swap( char *xp, char *yp ) 
{ 
    char temp[MAX_CHARS];
    strcpy( temp, xp );
    strcpy( xp, yp );
    strcpy( yp, temp ); 
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHARS   10

typedef struct product 
{
   char desc[MAX_CHARS]; /* string that describes a product eg. "bread" */
} product;

void swap( char *s1, char *s2 )
{
    char temp[MAX_CHARS];
    strcpy( temp, s1 );
    strcpy( s1, s2 );
    strcpy( s2, temp );
}

int main(void) 
{
    product p1 = { "Hello" };
    product p2 = { "World" };

    printf( "p1.desc = %s\n", p1.desc );
    printf( "p2.desc = %s\n", p2.desc );

    putchar( '\n' );

    swap( p1.desc, p2.desc );

    printf( "p1.desc = %s\n", p1.desc );
    printf( "p2.desc = %s\n", p2.desc );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
p1.desc = Hello
p2.desc = World

p1.desc = World
p2.desc = Hello
```

And in the if statement

```
if (arr[j].desc > arr[j+1].desc)
```

you have to compare the strings themselves like

```
if ( strcmp( arr[j].desc, arr[j+1].desc ) > 0 )
```

Also pay attention that you are not swapping the structures. You are only swapping their data members desc, It is not the same as to sort the structures.

To swap objects of the structure type the function swap can look the following way

```
void swap( product *p1, product *p2 )
{
    product temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_CHARS   10

typedef struct product 
{
   char desc[MAX_CHARS]; /* string that describes a product eg. "bread" */
} product;

void swap( product *p1, product *p2 )
{
    product temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp; 
}

int main(void) 
{
    product p1 = { "Hello" };
    product p2 = { "World" };

    printf( "p1.desc = %s\n", p1.desc );
    printf( "p2.desc = %s\n", p2.desc );

    putchar( '\n' );

    swap( &p1, &p2 );

    printf( "p1.desc = %s\n", p1.desc );
    printf( "p2.desc = %s\n", p2.desc );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
p1.desc = Hello
p2.desc = World

p1.desc = World
p2.desc = Hello
```

Comment: I did what u told me and the strings disapeared, so whats wrong?

Comment: @MartimCorreia I do not know what you did. You could for example incorrectly copy the function.

Comment: @MartimCorreia See my updated post. I appended it with a demonstrative program.